# Installing a new library in Linux, and accessing it from my C code

Tags: c, linux, makefile, static-libraries

I am working on a project which requires me to download and use [this](http://code.google.com/p/cubesat-space-protocol/downloads/detail?name=cubesat-space-protocol-0.9.tar.gz&can=2&q=). Inside the downloaded folder, when extracted I am presented with three things:

1. A folder called "include"
2. A folder called "src"
3. A file called "Makefile"

After some research, I found out that I have to navigate to the directory which contains these files, and just type in the command `make`.

It seemed to install the library in my system. So I tried a sample bit of code which should use the library:

```
csp_conn_t * conn;
csp_packet_t * packet;
csp_socket_t * socket = csp_socket(0);
csp_bind(socket, PORT_4);
csp_listen(socket, MAX_CONNS_IN_Q);

while(1) {
    conn = csp_accept(socket, TIMEOUT_MAX);
    packet = csp_read(conn, TIMEOUT_NONE);
    printf(“%S\r\n”, packet->data);
    csp_buffer_free(packet);
    csp_close(conn);
}
```

That's all that was given for the sample server end of the code. So I decided to add these to the top:

```
#include <csp.h>
#include <csp_buffer.h>
#include <csp_config.h>
#include <csp_endian.h>
#include <csp_interface.h>
#include <csp_platorm.h>
```

Thinking I was on the right track, I tried to compile the code with gcc, but I was given this error:

```
csptest_server.c:1: fatal error: csp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I thought I may not have installed the library correctly after all, but to make sure, I found out I could check by running this command, and getting this result:

```
find /usr -iname csp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic/include/config/snd/sb16/csp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic/include/config/snd/sb16/csp.h
```

So it seems like the csp.h is installed, maybe I am referencing it incorrectly in the header include line? Any insight? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try to use the -I option of the gcc for the header files.. It might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `make` command is probably only building the library, but not installing it. You could try `sudo make install`. This is the "common" method, but I recommend you to check the library's documentation, if any.

The `sudo` command is only necessary if you have no permissions to write the system's include and library directories, which may be your case.

Another possibility (instead of installing the library) is telling GCC the location of the library's source code and generated binaries (by means of the -I and -L options of the `gcc` command.

Comment: I tried `sudo make install`, but it send up saying `make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.` I'll try your other suggestions now. Thanks!

Comment: I tried `gcc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic/include/config/snd/sb16/ csptest_server.c` and got this: `csptest_server.c:2: fatal error: csp_buffer.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.` Good thing is that it seems to have cleared csp.h, but not it can't find csp_buffer.h. I tried running `find /usr -iname csp_buffer.h` but it didn't give me anything.

Comment: This means that the person that created the `Makefile` script did not implement the "install" rule. You can either manually copy files to the appropriate system folders or pass the appropriate -I and -L arguments to `gcc`.

Comment: Isn't csp_buffer.h included in the package you downloaded?. In such case you must also -I all subdirectories in the source tree that contain required headers.

Comment: OK, I've downloaded the package. Try: `-I/path/to/package/include/csp -I/path/to/package/include/csp/interfaces`

Comment: Trying, but still not much luck. Quick question just to make sure we're on the same page. Did I need to do something specific with the `Makefile` prior to running these commands?

Comment: If `make` runs OK and builds the library, I think you should not modify the Makefile. Once you have generated the binaries, you should simply tell GCC where the header and binary files are... Do not use the header files from the linux Kernel source (i.e. do not -I/usr/src/linux-headers...). Just tell GCC about the library files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15380/discussion-between-claudix-and-capcom)

Answer (score 2):

That Makefile will not install anything, just translate the source into a binary format.

The `csp.h` in the Linux kernel has nothing to do with your project, it's just a naming collision, likely to happen with three letter names.

In your case, I would presume you need to add the include directory to the compilation flags for your server, like `gcc -I/path/to/csp/include/csp  csptest_server.c`.

(Next, you'll run into linker errors because you'll also want to specify `-L/path/to/csp -lcsp` so that the linker can find the binary code to link to.)

Comment: Ok, I will try that. But I am curious to know why a Makefile is included in the package then. There doesn't seem to be any documentation regarding what I should do with it.

Comment: I tried `gcc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-28-generic/include/config/snd/sb16/ csptest_server.c` and got this: `csptest_server.c:2: fatal error: csp_buffer.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.` Good thing is that it seems to have cleared csp.h, but not it can't find csp_buffer.h. I tried running `find /usr -iname csp_buffer.h` but it didn't give me anything.

Comment: As I said, you want to use the csp.h that comes with the project, not the one from the Linux kernel: http://code.google.com/p/cubesat-space-protocol/source/browse/libCSP/trunk/include/csp/csp.h

Comment: Ya, I tried that too. No matter what I try, I keep getting `csptest_server.c:1: fatal error: csp.h: No such file or directory`. I am certain I am giving it the correct path with `-I` as well, directly into the directory which contains `csp.h`.